# Calculated sum correct in HTML but not saving to Firebase?

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, angularfire

I am able to get the sum in the HTML correctly with following codes:

```
<ion-item type="text" formControlName="billValue" 
[(ngModel)]="retailerItemModel" name="billValue" ngDefaultControl >Total 
Bill Value Rs. {{ totalValue(retailerItemModel) || 0 | number: '1.2-2' }}
</ion-item>
```

I am using Firebase to save data with AngularFire service provider:

```
saveBill(billValue: any =[], ): firebase.Promise<any>{
  return this.afDatabase.list(`userProfile/${this.userId}/billList/`).push({
    billValue          
  })
}
```

The problem is after saving the firebase data shows array:

[image]

I want the sum of selected values to show not the array… Is there any way to do the calculation in HTML itself or controller for selected value… Following is the controller formula:

```
totalValue(retailerItemModel: any=[]){
  let total = 0;
  retailerItemModel.forEach((item) => {
    total += Number(item);
  })
  return total;
}
```

Kindly suggest before I break something... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
saveBill(billValue: any =[], ): firebase.Promise<any>{
  return this.afDatabase.list(`userProfile/${this.userId}/billList/`).push({
    billValue: totalValue(billValue)    
  })
}
```

Currently, you are saving the array.

Comment: Not working...`TypeError: this.totalValue is not a function`

Comment: @Disu I'm suggesting that you get access to the totalValue function if possible or create one similar to get the total. However, it's worth avoid duplicating code.

Comment: Oh my my... Superbly simple and obvious only after you know it... Thanks @camden_kid

Comment: Not sure, if you can help ... I am unable to get the itemName from the billList ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591988/get-item-name-from-ngfor for details