# Get Item Name from ngFor

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, angularfire2

I am selecting from following list:

```
<ion-select multiple="true" okText="Select" cancelText="Cancel" required 
[(ngModel)]="retailerItemModel" formControlName="retailerItem" 
name="retailerItem">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let item of itemList | async" 
[value]="item.itemPrice">
          {{item.itemName}} &nbsp;Rs.{{item.itemPrice}}
        </ion-option>            
      </ion-select>
```

I am calculating the totalValue with `item.itemPrice` as [value] (mentioned above) but I want to fetch the `item.itemName` too.. I am getting correct value of `itemPrice` but not getting `itemName`.. Pls suggest how to structure `[value]` to get the correct value for both itemName and itemPrice

[image]

Following is the TS file for getting the itemList:

```
public itemList: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
this.itemList = this.itemProvider.getItemList();
```

The itemProvider TS:

```
getItemList(): FirebaseListObservable<any>{
return this.afDatabase.list(`userProfile/${this.userId}/itemList/`);
}
```

Complete firebase output
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

```
saveItem(itemName: string, itemQuantity: number, itemUnit: string, itemPrice: number): firebase.Promise<any>{
return this.afDatabase.list(`userProfile/${this.userId}/itemList/`).push({      
  itemName,
  itemQuantity,
  itemUnit,
  itemPrice
});
```

}

Comment: Can you show the Firebase data structure too?

Comment: Can you add your itemList or item?

Comment: Added the firebase db structure image... I can add item.itemPrice bcoz `[value] = "item.itemPrice" but I want `item.itemName` too

Comment: you can have a method like `getValue(pass item object)` in `[value]`and there in that method return `"itemName"+'*'+"itemValue"` where `*` will be a delimiter

Comment: I can add `itemPrice` because `[value]=item.itemPrice` but I want `itemName` too ... the problem is the retailerItem is showing as an array... Need to understand how to manipulate value to get `itemName` in retailerItem formControl

Comment: From where you get the `itemName`? I can't see that on firebase db? Show full code of your `formcontrol`?

Comment: I have updated the itemProvider.. full formControl may not be verbose... Let me know if you still want it... I am not referring to itemName or itemPrice anywhere else @Sampath

Comment: I am using `[value]=item.itemPrice` to get the totalValue() of `item.itemPrice` ... I am looking for a way to fetch the `itemName` instead of item.itemPrice in the retailerItem formControlName?

Comment: What is the out put of this? `return this.afDatabase.list(`userProfile/${this.userId}/itemList/`);`.Can you show the  result of it?

Comment: Pls check the update @Sampath

Comment: Still, cannot see `itemName`? Where is it :D

Comment: Updated @Sampath

Comment: So you want when user choose the items, you can get all price and name of items, do you?

Comment: Yes I am getting itemPrice but not itemName through value

Comment: Need help??? Anyone???